# I have two docker-compose.yml files launching separate sites on the one machine. Both launch fine separately. But when launched together not

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have two docker-compose.yml  files in separate directories launching separate sites on the one machine. Both launch fine separately. But when the second is launched whilst the first is running the newly launched docker environment seems to close down the first environment and replace it with it's self.

Both yml files use unique ports for nginx and mysql and all the services have unique names.

Directory 1 yml file

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: gio-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    container_name: gio-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  db:
    container_name: gio-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
     - ./storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
       - 3307:3306
```

Directory 2 yml file

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    container_name: gio-project1-app
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19-alpine
    container_name: gio-project1-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8002:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  db:
    container_name: gio-project1-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
```

Below is the output from the command `docker ps` NB this is the anticipated output after the yml file in directory 1 is run

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                  NAMES
055465a5e73d   mysql:8.0           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 hours ago   Up 5 hours   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp, :::3307->3306/tcp   gio-db
27380f4f6cf6   nginx:1.19-alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 hours ago   Up 5 hours   0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp, :::8001->80/tcp                  gio-nginx
21f3052f9dba   docker_app          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   5 hours ago   Up 5 hours   9000/tcp                                               gio-app
```

OK so we now run  `docker-compose up` in Directory 2 - below is the unanticipated output. NB the reference to the service names in the docker-compose file in directory 1

```
Recreating gio-db    ... done
Recreating gio-app   ... done
Recreating gio-nginx ... done
Attaching to gio-project1-app, gio-project1-nginx, gio-project1-db
```

And so we check what is running with `docker ps`

```
1b19e7d3c47a   mysql:8.0           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   57 seconds ago       Up 57 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp, :::3308->3306/tcp   gio-project1-db
d1661431acb5   nginx:1.19-alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About a minute ago   Up 59 seconds   0.0.0.0:8002->80/tcp, :::8002->80/tcp                  gio-project1-nginx
ceff9c811cf7   docker_app          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   About a minute ago   Up 59 seconds   9000/tcp                                               gio-project1-app
```

We see the services listed in the yml file in directory 1 have gone to be replaced with those in yml directory 2.

A bit of a newbie with docker. Any help gratefully received. : - )

Comment: What are the actual names of the two directories?  If the two Compose files are in subdirectories that have the same name that could lead to a symptom like this.